# When should I let my contractor know that I won't be staying?

Tags: contractors, consulting

I am currently employed as a contractor for Company X through a consulting agency until mid June 2016.  The consulting agency has a very good history of converting contractors to FTEs with Company X.

I am on very good terms with my agency supervisor and the overall agency manager that works with Company X to supply them new contractors.

I have recently decided to move across the country with my family.  My intention is to see through the contract.  Should I let my agency supervisor know of my decision now or wait until I hear through the agency what Company X decides about my contract?

Comment: I'd wait until the company makes a decision about converting your contract, or when it comes to the required notice period as specified in your contract - whichever comes first.

Comment: thanks to all for the replies. @Joe Strazzere The Company X that I am working for does not have an office where I am moving to and neither does the consulting agency. I am concerned about maintaining a good relation with my agency.

Answer (score 12):

Unless there is some overriding reason, you should never let the company know you're leaving until you have to.

You yourself may change your mind, you may be relegated tasks you won't relish, a bunch of potential negatives are there. If you don't tell them then it's just business as usual until you hand in your notice, and you're under no obligation to inform them prior to that.

Comment: Note that one such reason would be knowing that your company/manager handles long notice periods gracefully and gratefully. Good companies can earn the kind of reputation that leads to people announcing months in advance that they'll be moving on with a lot of advantages for both parties.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the contract doesn't spell out how you go about moving on, your approach could depend on whether you could afford - or perhaps even prefer - to be let go sooner than the end of June.

Even when seemingly on good terms, telling a company you will be leaving might spark quite hostile reactions.

In similar situations, I have not mentioned me leaving until I could infer that they were planning on me staying. If they begin mentioning you in an 'after Summer' context, you should probably spill the beans.